# Replace all except the first occurrence of a substring in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string which looks like below

```
string = "SELECT sdfdsf SELECT sdrrr SELECT 5445ff"
```

Now I want to replace every occurrence of `SELECT` except the first one with `@@@SELECT` so that in the end string looks like this

```
"SELECT sdfdsf @@@SELECT sdrrr @@@SELECT 5445ff"
```

Now Python `replace()` replaces all occurrence of SELECT.

```
string = string.replace("SELECT", "@@@SELECT)
```

So the string becomes

```
"@@@SELECT sdfdsf @@@SELECT sdrrr @@@SELECT 5445ff"
```

How do I ensure except the first instance, everything else is replaced?

**Note:** The string can have n occurrences of `SELECT`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With additional "*reversed*" substitution step:

```
s = "SELECT sdfdsf SELECT sdrrr SELECT 5445ff"
res = s.replace("SELECT", "@@@SELECT").replace("@@@SELECT", "SELECT", 1)
print(res)
```

The output:

```
SELECT sdfdsf @@@SELECT sdrrr @@@SELECT 5445ff
```

---

A more sophisticated, but ensuring target word boundaries, could be as below:

```
import re

def make_replacer():
    rpl = ''
    def inner(m):
        nonlocal rpl
        res = rpl + m.group()
        rpl = '@@@'
        return res
    return inner

s = "SELECT sdfdsf SELECT sdrrr SELECT 5445ff"
res = re.sub(r'\bSELECT\b', make_replacer(), s)
print(res)   # SELECT sdfdsf @@@SELECT sdrrr @@@SELECT 5445ff
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.count` with `re.sub`:

```
import re, itertools
c = itertools.count()
string = "SELECT sdfdsf SELECT sdrrr SELECT 5445ff"
r = re.sub(r"\bSELECT\b", lambda x:x.group() if not next(c) else f'@@@{x.group()}', string)
```

Output:

```
'SELECT sdfdsf @@@SELECT sdrrr @@@SELECT 5445ff'
```

---

However, if `SELECT` is always placed at the start of the string, you can use a negative lookbehind:

```
r = re.sub('(?<!^)SELECT', lambda x:f'@@@{x.group()}', string)
```

Output:

```
'SELECT sdfdsf @@@SELECT sdrrr @@@SELECT 5445ff'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `partition` and `replace`. The working code looks like:

```
string = "SELECT sdfdsf SELECT sdrrr SELECT 5445ff"
parts = string.partition("SELECT")  # returns a tuple
results = parts[0] + parts[1] + parts[2].replace("SELECT", "@@@SELECT")

print(results)
```

So you will get:

> SELECT sdfdsf @@@SELECT sdrrr @@@SELECT 5445ff

If `string = "Blabla is SELECT sdfdsf SELECT sdrrr SELECT 5445ff"`, you will get:

> Blabla is SELECT sdfdsf @@@SELECT sdrrr @@@SELECT 5445ff

Answer (score 3):

How about just skipping the first 3 letters of what you have?

```
string = string.replace("SELECT", "@@@SELECT)[3:]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

def removeExceptFirst(s, old, new):
    i = s.find(old) + len(old)
    newStr = s[0:i]
    newStr += s[i:].replace(old, new)
    return newStr

print(removeExceptFirst("SELECT sdfdsf SELECT sdrrr SELECT 5445ff", "SELECT", "@@@SELECT"))
```

The Output:

> SELECT sdfdsf @@@SELECT sdrrr @@@SELECT 5445ff

Answer (score 1):

One more approach:

```
import re
from itertools import chain, repeat
string = 'SELECT sdfdsf SELECT sdrrr SELECT 5445ff'
string = ''.join(x + s for x, s in zip(chain(['', 'S'], repeat('@@@S')), re.split(r'\bS(?=ELECT\b)', string)))
print(string)
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT sdfdsf @@@SELECT sdrrr @@@SELECT 5445ff
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code (more simple and only use `split` and `replace`)

```
string = "SELECT sdfdsf SELECT sdrrr SELECT 5445ff"
string = "SELECT " + string.split('SELECT', 1)[1].strip().replace('SELECT', '@@@SELECT').strip()
```

But if there's a text before the SELECT, use

```
string = "SELECT sdfdsf SELECT sdrrr SELECT 5445ff"
string = string.split('SELECT', 1)[0].strip() + " SELECT " + string.split('SELECT', 1)[1].strip().replace('SELECT', '@@@SELECT').strip()
```

That code remove the first `SELECT` and then replace all the `SELECT` sub-string and then add the `SELECT` string to the main string