# Replacing a specific item in a string when that item occurs more than once, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, substring

Let's say I have the following:

```py
str1='restart'
```

I want to replace 'r' with '#' but only the second occurrence of 'r' and not the first, using the function replace()

Expected return is:

```py
str1='resta#t'
```

I know how to replace either all the occurrences of 'r' `str1.replace('r','#')`, or a number of occurrences of 'r' starting from the first one `str1.replace('r','#',1)`, but cannot figure how to replace just the second occurrence and not the other ones.

Comment: Hi there, any specific reason why you must use the "replace" method?

Comment: You can replace up to N occurences, then just replace the 1st one back. Does this answer your question? [Replace all except the first occurrence of a substring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58353516/replace-all-except-the-first-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-python)

Comment: @GinoMempin yes that does answer my question precisely, thank you.

Comment: Thanks to all who took out time to answer the question, most of the solutions worked but were a tad too advanced for my knowledge as I'm a beginner at programming. As I progress with learning Python, I will definitely come back to this question and try out all the different solutions given by you all!

Comment: @nandevers that's because I have just started to learn Python and this was an exercise question I came across that specifically warranted the use of the replace method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does the trick.

```
string = "restart"
result = string.replace("r", "#").replace("#", "r", 1)
print(result) # resta#t
```

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't solve the problem then I need more detail.

```
str1.replace(str1[5],'#')
```

or

```
r2 = str1.find(r, 2)
str1.replace(r2, '#')
```

Comment: If you found the right answer from any user, Make sure to click the tick.

Comment: The solutions you gave did not work out, check the answer give by MaxK, it gave the precise solution I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split and replace for the same.

```
str1 = "restart"
split_ch = "r"
new_ch = "#"
split_list = str1.split(split_ch, 1)
result = split_list[0]+ split_ch + split_list[1].replace(split_ch,new_ch, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regex replacement here:

```py
str1 = "restart"
output = re.sub(r'r([^r]*)r', r'r\1#', str1, 1)
print(output)  # resta#t
```

The pattern matches the first `r`, captures optional non `r` following letters, followed by the second `r`.  We then replace, swapping in `#` for the second `r`.  Note that the fourth parameter to `re.sub` is `1`, meaning that this replacement will only happen once.

Answer (score 0):

One way that maybe gets it done for you!

```
def replace_second(input_:str, letter:str = 'r', replace:str ='other'):
    idx = [i for i, _ in enumerate(input_) if _ ==letter]
    return input_[:idx[1]] + input_[idx[1]:].replace(letter, replace)
```

Try it out yourself:

```
replace_second('restart', 'r', '#')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str1='restart'
str1 = [*str1]
i = 0
j = 0
for string in str1:
    j += 1
    print(string, j)
    if string == 'r':
        i+=1
        if i ==2:
            str1[j-1] = '#'
        else:
            continue
print(''.join(str1))
```

Definitely not the best, but this works...